# Net http connecting over plaintext even though SSL options are set

Tags: ruby

Using the `net/http` gem in Ruby, I am simply trying to connect over port 443/tcp using the following:

```
response = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port, @proxy_ip, @proxy_port, use_ssl: true, verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE).start do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  headers.each { |key, value| request[key] = value } unless headers.empty?
  http.request(request)
end
```

However, the response is giving me an error showing that I'm connecting over port 80:

```
[12] pry(main)> response.body
=> "<html>\r\n<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

My initial way of connecting is this way:

```
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, @proxy_ip, @proxy_port, use_ssl: true, verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
```

However, I needed to implement authentication for the proxy, and apparently I need to do this with the `HTTP.new`, so this code block was revised to try accommodating proxy authentication.

I have tried taking out `@proxy_ip` and `@proxy_port`, but this results in *another* error:

```
response = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true, verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE).start do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  headers.each { |key, value| request[key] = value } unless headers.empty?
  http.request(request)
end
```

error:

```
TypeError: Failed to open TCP connection to {:use_ssl=>true, :verify_mode=>0}:80 (no implicit conversion of Hash into String)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:960:in `initialize'
Caused by TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:960:in `initialize'
```

My uri is just basically `https://www.google.com/page?query=1&query=2`

I'm just simply trying to make an HTTPS call while authenticating to a proxy (if one exists and is assigned in the environment variables).

Answer (score 1):

The `Net::HTTP.new` constructor does not support SSL options directly. You have to add them later in the sequence. The signature for `Net:HTTP.new` is:

```
Net::HTTP.new(host, port, proxy_host, proxy_port, proxy_user, proxy_pass)
```

There is also a requirement to set `use_ssl` **before** `start` is called, otherwise the proxy setup will fail.

So with those things in mind, this should work:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(host, port, proxy_host, proxy_port, proxy_user, proxy_pass)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

res = http.start { |connection|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  headers.each { |key, value| request[key] = value } unless headers.empty?
  connection.request(request)
}
```